# L suffix in long integer in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2.x there was a `L` suffix after long integer. As Python 3 treats all integers as long integer this has been removed. From [What's New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

> The repr() of a long integer doesn’t include the trailing L anymore, so code that unconditionally strips that character will chop off the last digit instead. (Use str() instead.)

From this I get that `repr()` won't show `L` suffix, but `str()` will have the `L` suffix. But in Python 3.3.3 none of them are showing `L` suffix.

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> repr(2 ** 64)
'18446744073709551616'
>>> str(2 ** 64)
'18446744073709551616'
```

Shouldn't the output of `str()` be `18446744073709551616L` as per the doc? I could not find anything in [What's New In Python 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html), [What's New In Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html) and [What's New In Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) that says `L` suffix is removed from `str()` too. 3.2 says that:

> The str() of a float or complex number is now the same as its repr().

But it says nothing about integer.

From which version of Python `L` suffix is removed in `str()` too? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers (4th point)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You misunderstood the documentation.

The remark is aimed at people trying to strip the `L` from `repr()` **in Python 2**. Those people could use `str()` instead and get the same number without having to strip the `L` each time.

In other words, `str()`, when used on a long integer in Python 2, is the better method to convert the number to a string, as it will never add the `L` suffix that `repr()` would add:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 28 2014, 17:17:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print repr(1L)
1L
>>> print str(1L)
1
```

Python 3 will never add the `L`. Not when using `repr()`, and not when using `str()`. There would be no point; **all** integers in Python 3 are long integers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I misunderstood the documentation.