# numpy sign and fraction

Tags: python, numpy, fractions

What is the pitfall I'm falling into (apart from blindly applying a `numpy` method to some object it was probably not designed for)?

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 16:41:13) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy, fractions
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.8.2'
>>> numpy.sign(1)
1
>>> fractions.Fraction(1)
Fraction(1, 1)
>>> numpy.sign(fractions.Fraction(1))
-1
>>>
```

Comment: Numpy doesn't support Fractions, AFAIK.

Comment: Which version of numpy are you using? (Check `numpy.__version__`.)

Comment: I don't know what version you are using, but for me, this works.

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6229

Comment: I added the `numpy` version: 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with the particular version of numpy you are using. It works for me. Though in general, numpy may not support fractions, going through the documentation of `numpy.sign`, no special case about fractions is mentioned per se, only that it accepts numbers and outputs the sign.

```
In [14]: import numpy, fractions

In [15]: numpy.sign(1)
    ...: 
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: fractions.Fraction(1)
    ...: 
Out[16]: Fraction(1, 1)

In [17]: numpy.sign(fractions.Fraction(1))
Out[17]: 1L
```

Comment: What does the L mean in `1L`?

Comment: @Jellby Its just a suffix to signify long integer. You can read on some other aspects here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24059842/1860929